# I want to get sum of an alias in mysql sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get sum of a resulting from a sub query in mysql. Here is a snippet of my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (st.accountNumber) AS ac,
       (SELECT CASE cmo.mode 
                    WHEN 'FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount)
                    WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                    WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * 1 
                    WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount)
                    WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                    WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                END AS computedCommissionAmount 
           FROM s_cm cm
           JOIN....
            AND cs.active=1 
            AND CASE cmo.mode 
                    WHEN 'FIXED' THEN TRUE 
                    WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' THEN TRUE
                    WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' THEN SUM(st.convertedAmount) .... 
                    END ) AS TOTAL_SUM 
           FROM s_st st 
          INNER 
           JOIN ....
          GROUP 
             BY st.serviceID, 
                st.convertedCurrencyID;
```

How how can i get summation of `TOTAL_SUM` which is an alias. If i add `SUM` before select as seen below it fails with an error

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

This Failed to work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(st.accountNumber) AS ac,
       SUM((
       SELECT CASE cmo.mode 
                  WHEN 'FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                  WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                  WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * 1 
                  WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                  WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
                  WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
              END AS computedCommissionAmount 
         FROM s_cm cm 
         JOIN.... 
          AND cs.active=1 
          AND CASE cmo.mode 
                  WHEN 'FIXED' THEN TRUE 
                  WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' THEN TRUE
                  WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' THEN SUM(st.convertedAmount) .... 
              END )) AS TOTAL_SUM 
         FROM s_st st 
        INNER 
         JOIN .... 
        GROUP 
           BY st.serviceID, 
              st.convertedCurrencyID;
```

Someone help

This is the whole query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(st.accountNumber) as ac, oc.clientID as ownerClientID,oc.clientName as ownerClient,
    s.serviceID,  st.settlementLogID, s.serviceName AS service,  SUM(st.convertedAmount) AS totalAmount, 
    ss.commissionModelID,   st.convertedCurrencyID,
         SUM((
            SELECT  case cmo.mode WHEN 'FIXED' then cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
            WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' then (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
            WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' then cs.fixedChargeAmount * 1 
            WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_FIXED' then cs.fixedChargeAmount * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
            WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE' then (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount) 
            WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_PERCENTAGE' then (cs.percentageAmount/100) * SUM(st.convertedAmount)
      END as computedCommissionAmount 
      FROM s_commissionModels cm 
            JOIN s_commissionSettings cs on cm.commissionModelID=cs.commissionModelID 
            JOIN s_commissionModes cmo on cmo.commissionModeID = cm.commissionModeID 
        WHERE cm.commissionModelID = 2 AND cm.active=1 AND cs.active=1 
        AND 
         case cmo.mode 
            WHEN 'FIXED' then true when 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' then true
            WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' then SUM(st.convertedAmount) between cs.minTransactionAmount AND cs.maxTransactionAmount
            WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_FIXED' then SUM(st.convertedAmount) between cs.minTransactionCount AND cs.maxTransactionCount
            WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE' then SUM(st.convertedAmount) between cs.minTransactionAmount AND cs.maxTransactionAmount
            WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_PERCENTAGE' then SUM(st.convertedAmount) between cs.minTransactionCount AND cs.maxTransactionCount end 
         AND cs.beneficiaryClientID =2 )) as TOTAL_SUM 
         FROM s_settlementTransactions st 
            INNER JOIN s_services s ON st.serviceID = s.serviceID  
            INNER JOIN clients oc on s.ownerClientID = oc.clientID 
            INNER JOIN currencies cu on st.convertedCurrencyID = cu.currencyID 
            INNER JOIN s_serviceSettings ss ON st.serviceID = ss.serviceID AND st.payerClientID = ss.payerClientID 
            LEFT JOIN bankBranches bb ON s.settlementBankBranchID = bb.bankBranchID 
            LEFT JOIN banks b ON bb.bankID = b.bankID 
            INNER JOIN countries c ON oc.countryID = c.countryID 
        WHERE st.overallStatus IN (140, 217) 
            AND st.settlementLogID = 94 AND st.overallSettlementStatus = 1 AND st.settlementUnit = 'account' 
            GROUP BY st.serviceID, st.convertedCurrencyID;
```

Comment: I can't read that code, please format it properly.

Comment: This is not a mimimal question, and I can't really read your code.  Please take a few moments and format your query.

Comment: @HoneyBadger This is done

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is done. Help out please

Comment: While better, it still is not readable. However, you seem to be using a group by without aggregation in combination with distinct. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to get sum of the alias (TOTAL_SUM) returned by the subquery

Comment: @lewie That's not really formatted, I've added an edit. I'd recommend reading a SQL style guide. Maybe: https://www.sqlstyle.guide/ It doesn't really matter what you do as long as it's organized and consistent. It pays dividends both with your own debugging time and it's better for people reading your stuff. I'm not trying to be overly critical, but if someone at work sent me a query formatted like that I would think one of two things 1.) They are inconsiderate and can't take 30 seconds to do it correctly 2.) They don't appreciate the importance of proper formatting, which is worrisome.

Comment: @Error_2646 Thanks for the input.. I had copy pasted directly from the terminal. Am still stuck on a way to get summation of alias TOTAL_SUM

Comment: @HoneyBadger am trying to get summation of alias TOTAL_SUM

Comment: @Error_2646 i have pasted the whole query

Comment: @HoneyBadger i have pasted the whole query. Check again please

Comment: All those non-aggregated columns are not in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that your `case` is wrong.  You probably intend conditional aggregation:

```
SUM(CASE cmo.mode 
        WHEN 'FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * st.convertedAmount
        WHEN 'FIXED_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * st.convertedAmount
        WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * 1 
        WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_FIXED' THEN cs.fixedChargeAmount * st.convertedAmount
        WHEN 'TIERED_AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * st.convertedAmount 
        WHEN 'TIERED_COUNT_PERCENTAGE' THEN (cs.percentageAmount/100) * st.convertedAmount)
    END) AS computedCommissionAmount
```

Your query may have other problems.  It seems way over-complicated for counting distinct values of a specific column.

Comment: I have removed some functionality to just highlight where am stuck at.. getting summation of alias TOTAL_SUM

Comment: I have pasted the whole query